# ASP .NET Annotation on property getter only

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, properties, annotations

I use Linq to SQL on a ASP .NET MVC project.
My generated classes for a table have properties for every fields in table and I put [JsonIgnore] annotation on some to avoid them to be serialized.
But when I deserialize a Json to build my object, those properties are ignored.

What I want is that property getter is ignored, but not the setter.

Part of my User class (the UserMetadata class allow me to put annotation on properties defined on partial class generated by Linq) :

```
[MetadataType(typeof(UserMetadata))]
public partial class User
{
    internal sealed class UserMetadata
    {
        [JsonIgnore]
        public string password { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public string seed { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public System.Nullable<System.DateTime> token_expire_date { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance !